# AWS - RDS - MySQL - out of memory

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I am running a MySQL instance with the following settings:

db.t2.micro
vCPU 1
1 GB
20G
Free Space 19404.5546875
14 tables
Biggest table have about 2000 records
All the rest - 3 to 10 records

So this is the smallest (using it for testing) but it were running fine until yesterday (2021-02-13).

I do use a few inner joins this one below been the one with the most. I were able to run it previously but now it just timeout and uses a few G to do it. Any suggestions?

```
'''Select U.sen_id,
    U.dev_id,
    U.sen_comment,
    t1.tl_value as lat,
    t2.tl_value as lon,
    t3.tl_value as alt,
    t4.tl_value as speed,
    t5.tl_value as batv,
    t5.tl_value as deg,
    t1.time as times
    From user_device U
    INNER JOIN tracker_lat_lon t1 ON t1.sen_id = U.sen_id AND t1.tl_id = 1
    INNER JOIN tracker_lat_lon t2 ON t2.sen_id = U.sen_id AND t2.tl_id = 2
    INNER JOIN tracker_lat_lon t3 ON t3.sen_id = U.sen_id AND t3.tl_id = 3
    INNER JOIN tracker_lat_lon t4 ON t4.sen_id = U.sen_id AND t4.tl_id = 4
    INNER JOIN tracker_lat_lon t5 ON t5.sen_id = U.sen_id AND t5.tl_id = 5
    INNER JOIN tracker_lat_lon t6 ON t6.sen_id = U.sen_id AND t6.tl_id = 6
    Where t1.sen_id = (SELECT UD.sen_id
    FROM user_device UD
    WHERE UD.dev_id = 'xxxxxxxx')
    ORDER BY t1.time DESC LIMIT 1 '''
```

[AWS Metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lEMR.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to identify the source of the memory utilization, and troubleshoot low freeable memory, check the following link:
[here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/low-freeable-memory-rds-mysql-mariadb/)

Comment: Thanks, I will read this, hopefully I will be able to fine tune my db a bit better

Comment: Can you please score my question? As you answer did help me and the system have now blocked me as the AI perceives I am not contributing.